Jest Test Failure: Class Constructor Arguments Not Accessible in Methods
I'm encountering an issue with my Jest tests for a SearchDbService class. The first test is failing because the arguments passed to the constructor don't seem to exist within the class methods when debugging. Specifically, there's no this keyword visible in the debugger, which is causing some functionalities to not work as expected.
Code
Here's the relevant part of my SearchDbService class:
class SearchDbService extends BaseDatabaseService<SearchStatistics> {
  constructor(
    private crawlerDB: ControlledPgPromiseDb,
    private logger: Logger,
    private statistics: SearchStatistics
 ) {
    super(crawlerDB, logger, statistics)
  }


  async processBatchOfSearches(
    engineNames: string[],
    batchSize: number
  ): Promise<SearchEntity[]> {
    const searches = await this.getBatchOfSearchAndSetPending({
      batchSize,
      engineNames,
    })

    if (searches.length === 0) {
      return []
    }

    const nonDuplicatedSearches =
      await this.handleAllDuplicateSearches(searches)

    const validSearches = await this.handleInvalidSearches(
      nonDuplicatedSearches
    )

    // update search statistics
    this.statistics.updateSearchAmount({
      total: searches.length,
      valid: validSearches.length,
      invalid: searches.length - validSearches.length,
    })

    return validSearches
  }
}

Here's my Jest test setup and the test case:
// Mock dependencies
jest.mock('~/utils/database/BaseDatabaseService.js')
jest.mock('uuid')
jest.mock('~searchService/database/searchSQL.js')

describe('SearchDbService', () => {
  let mockStatistics = new SearchStatistics()
  let mockLogger = { error: jest.fn() } as unknown as jest.Mocked<Logger>
  let searchDbService: SearchDbService
  let mockCrawlerDB: ControlledPgPromiseDb

  beforeEach(() => {
    mockCrawlerDB = {
      manyOrNone: jest.fn(),
      query: jest.fn(),
      helpers: {
        ColumnSet: jest.fn(),
        insert: jest.fn(),
      },
    } as unknown as jest.Mocked<ControlledPgPromiseDb>

    mockStatistics = new SearchStatistics()
    mockLogger = { error: jest.fn() } as unknown as jest.Mocked<Logger>

    searchDbService = new SearchDbService(
      mockCrawlerDB,
      mockLogger,
      mockStatistics
    )
  })

  describe('processBatchOfSearches', () => {
    it('should process a batch of searches successfully', async () => {
      // Arrange
      const engineNames = ['bing', 'google']
      const batchSize = 10
      const mockSearches = [
        {
          id: '123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000',
          request: {
            subscriberId: '123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174001',
            query: 'test query',
            engine: 'engine1',
          },
        },
      ] as unknown as SearchEntity[]
      searchDbService.getBatchOfSearchAndSetPending = jest
        .fn()
        .mockResolvedValue(mockSearches)
      searchDbService.handleAllDuplicateSearches = jest
        .fn()
        .mockResolvedValue(mockSearches)
      searchDbService.handleInvalidSearches = jest
        .fn()
        .mockResolvedValue(mockSearches)

      // Act
      const result = await searchDbService.processBatchOfSearches(
        engineNames,
        batchSize
      )

      // Assert
      expect(
        searchDbService.getBatchOfSearchAndSetPending
      ).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ batchSize, engineNames })
      expect(searchDbService.handleAllDuplicateSearches).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        mockSearches
      )
      expect(searchDbService.handleInvalidSearches).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        mockSearches
      )
      expect(result).toEqual(mockSearches)
      expect(mockStatistics.updateSearchAmount).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
        total: 1,
        valid: 1,
        invalid: 0,
      })
    })
  })
})

Problem
When running the tests, the first test fails because the this.statistics object doesn't exist within the processBatchOfSearches method. When debugging, I noticed that there's no this keyword visible in the debugger for the class methods.
This issue is causing the following line to fail:
this.statistics.updateSearchAmount({
  total: searches.length,
  valid: validSearches.length,
  invalid: searches.length - validSearches.length,
})

The test expects mockStatistics.updateSearchAmount to be called, but it's not because this.statistics is undefined.
Question

Why aren't the constructor arguments (crawlerDB, logger, statistics) accessible within the class methods during the Jest test?
How can I modify my test setup or class implementation to ensure that these properties are correctly initialized and accessible within the class methods?
Is there something wrong with how I'm mocking the dependencies or setting up the test that could be causing this issue?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!
